# form with image loading from picture folder not showing correctly

Tags: lwuit

i am developing an application to show pictures as slide show.there are two containers. first container showing links.when user click on link next containers appears and show images.  But the second container is displaying but it is at the back of first container. how can i avoid this

please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should post your code, but a guess is you need to edit your CSS and add float:right to the image container CSS perhaps.

```
<div id="link">Some link</div><div id="photo" style="float:right;"></div>
```

Just a guess but that could be what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

How do you replace the containers? If you use something like `parentForm.replace(firstContainer, secondContainer, transition);` this should work just fine.